# Custom HTML form using PHP - help with ajax/username validation

Tags: php, ajax, forms, html, validation

I currently have a working registration form I created on my page. It's an HTML form and I coded PHP to have it create the user in our WP_user table and email us with info from the form. The PHP is in the functions.php file, and there are no issues with it working but it currently has to be submitted and if the created username already exists, it will show error message on blank index page and then redirect back to the form. WE would like it to validate and show if the username is available or not while on the form. I think this has to be done with AJAX but I'm not sure. Here is the PHP code from functions.php:

```
    if (username_exists($user)){

echo 'Username already exists. Please wait while we redirect you back to the form';
    die("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"5;url=".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."\"/>");


}

if ( !username_exists( $user )  && !email_exists( $email ) ) {
   $user_id = wp_create_user( $user, $pass, $email );
   if( !is_wp_error($user_id) ) {
       //user has been created
       $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
       $user->set_role( 'subscriber' );

       wp_mail( $to, $email_subject, $message, $headers);


       //Redirect
       wp_redirect( 'http://www.dev.smithhonig.com/thank-you' );
       exit;
   } else {
       //$user_id is a WP_Error object. Manage the error
   }
}
```

Again, this works perfectly but we want to try an option to validate while on the form when the username field is clicked out of. I'm not familiar with AJAX too much or where to implement it for WP so I want to use the best practices here. Thank you

UPDATE:

Here is some code for the AJAX call I'm using.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#username').on('change', function(){
    let user = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<WP_AJAX_URL_HERE>',
        data: {action: 'verify_username', username: user},
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            // Write code to show the message to user here
        },
        error: function(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
});
```

As well as additional PHP in the functions file:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_verify_username', 'check_username' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_verify_username', 'check_username' );
function check_username(){
$username = $_POST['username'];
if( username_exists( $username ) ) {
    echo $username . ' already taken.';
}else {
    echo 'Hurray ' . $username . ' is available.';
}

exit;
}
```

Comment: Hello @H.Norman - good questions tend to show some research/implementation effort on the part of the asker. Start [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/) for a solid introduction to using AJAX in WordPress, then let us know if and where you get stuck =]

Comment: I should have added earlier, but I just updated with code I was using for the AJAX portion. My problem is the error I get for the third line of the AJAX call, I think the 'let' command is giving me problems. But I believe the issue was this code was posted in the functions file. Should the ajax call be put in a code block on the form page itself?

Comment: The `let` itself looks fine - hard to say what might cause the error without seeing the message. The JavaScript should be fine whether in an external script or a script block somewhere in the document, so long as the jQuery lib itself is referenced first. In general, it looks like it should work, to me - so long as `<WP_AJAX_URL_HERE>` contains the correct URL ([you can use `wp_localize_script()` to pass this URL to your JavaScript](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/enqueuing/#localize)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got AJAX working for me.

1. I digested this tutorial. https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins
2. I created an external JS file and enqueued after jQuery because of its dependency on jQuery.
3. I created a PHP function to respond to the AJAX call by echoing what was sent.
4. When that worked, I made the PHP function send the data I needed.

I think what you have should work. If the `let` declaration gives you an error, try it with `var` instead. This is stupid, I know, but if `var` doesn't work then the error is in the right side of the expression.

I would replace `url: '<WP_AJAX_URL_HERE>'` with `ajaxurl` and see if that helps.